# Use Whitehead 's theorem to show that a $S^{\infty}$ is contractible.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, definition, homotopy-theory

Use Whitehead 's theorem to show that a $S^{\infty}= \cup_{n =1}^{\infty} S^n$ is contractible.

**Whitehead thm.**

> [image]

And I know that a space is contractible iff it is homotopy equivalent to a point.

**My questions are:**

what are the 2 connected CW complexes that I should consider and what is the map between them and how can I show that this map induces isomorphisms from $\pi_{n}(X)$ to $\pi_{n}(Y)$ for all $n.$ Could anyone help me please in this?

Comment: You always have a map from the one-point space to any (nonempty) space, so consider $f: \{*\} \to S^{\infty}$. Then what are the homotopy groups of each of these spaces?

Comment: I do not know I will search the book and answer you @kamills. but could you tell me please which pg of AT give us the information you mentioned in your first statement?

Comment: To compute $\pi_n(S^{\infty})$ take a map $g:S^n\to S^{\infty}$. Note that its image must be contained in some $S^m$, since the image is a compact. Then you can contract $g$, inside $S^{m+1}$, to a constant map.

Comment: Why we should take a map from $S^n$ and how I can contract this $g$ to a constant map ?@conditionalMethod

Comment: The [definition of homotopy group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group#Definition) is certain equivalence classes of maps from the corresponding sphere. How would you contract, along a sphere, a map that has image contained in the equator of the sphere?

Comment: @conditionalMethod frankly speaking I am overthinking I do not know :(

Comment: You can [contract the equator sliding it up to the north pole](https://youtu.be/xxaabfevueQ), for example.

Comment: do I have to calculate $\pi_{n} (X)$ and $\pi_{n} (Y)$ for each $n$?@conditionalMethod

Comment: @conditionalMethod is the solution of this problem similar to the solution of problem #1.2.20 in AT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim:** Any map $* \to S^\infty$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, i.e. induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups.

It suffices to show $\pi_n S^\infty=0$ for all $n$. To do this we can use the following lemma (whose proof I leave to you as an exercise):

**Lemma:** Any continuous function $X\to S^k$ which is not surjective is null-homotopic.

*Proof sketch for Claim:* To compute $\pi_n S^\infty$, consider a continuous function $f\colon S^n \to S^\infty$. Since the image of $f$ is compact and $\cup_k S^k$ is given the colimit (weak) topology, the image of $f$ must be contained in some $S^k$ for a finite $k$, and hence $f$ is not surjective onto $S^{k+1}$. Therefore by Lemma $f$ is null-homotopic in $S^{k+1}$ and hence in $S^\infty$.

Now we can conclude $S^\infty$ is contractible by Whitehead's theorem.

Comment: Is this claim proved in AT? if so on which pg.?

Comment: Is this Lemma found in AT? if so at which page?

Comment: I feel like these can be found in Hatcher but I'm not sure where, it's possible at least one of them is an exercise. I will give you a hint for the lemma though: supposing $f\colon X\to S^k$ is continuous and $p\in S^k$ is *not* in the image of $f$, construct a homotopy between $f$ and the function which is constantly $-p$ (write down a straight-line homotopy, but normalize it so it is on the sphere).